# Do Zombies with skulls drop the skulls?

Tags: terraria

I have been playing Terraria for a while and I have always seen zombies with skulls on their heads. I think the skulls are cool so I have always wanted to wear one of those. So I need to know, can those Zombies drop their skulls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no zombies with skulls on their head. What you are probably referring to is a swamp zombie. And although it looks like a skull its not, all zombies have a chance to drop a shackle, a zombie arm, and a zombie banner.
Some [zombies](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Zombie) also have their specific drops :

#### Those you can encounter in a regular night :

- Slimed zombie : drops gel
- Pincushion zombie : drops arrows

#### Those that appear commonly inside biomes, or events.

- Rain zombie (during rain) : drops Rain coat, Rain hat.
- Zombie eskimo (surface snow biome) : drops eskimo armor
- Spore/Mushroom zombie (hardmode mushroom biome) : drops significantly more coins
- *exception* : Disguised zombie (halloween) : doesn't drop anything but little money.

#### Those that appear rarely

- Doctor bones (jungle biome) : drops his Archaeologist's hat
- The groom (blood moon) : drops his top hat

Answer (score 0):

I killed skeletron and got the skull vanity item. I think is rare drop cause I killed skeletron about 3 times and only got it once.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your referring to Swamp Zombies. [image]

Unfortunately, they do not drop their heads, nor do any zombies in general.